# Copy assignment of shared_ptr causes segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, gcc

I am compiling using gcc 5.4.

I have some resource `SpritePack` that I manage by storing `std::shared_ptr<SpritePack>` in a `std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<SpritePack>>`. So when I construct a `SpritePack` with `make_shared`, the reference counter should be above 0 as long as the map exists. In the complete code (too big to include everything here), I can printout the reference counter and see that it is at 4 at the point in code shown below.

My problem occurs here:

```
void Sprite::setSpritePack(std::shared_ptr<SpritePack> spritePack) {
    _spritePack = spritePack;
}
```

Where `_spritePack` is a member of type `std::shared_ptr<SpritePack>` variable of the class Sprite. Why does gcc not let me copy/assign a shared pointer?

I have double check the shared_ptrs at various points in my code, and I kno for certain that at every point where the shared_ptr in question is passed (by value), it points to the same memory location. The resource is not moved around in the contianer either, because the resource is heap allocated and I manage the pointer instead.

No destructor is called before this segmentation fault either.

The problem occurs in the assignment, and gdb prints out the following backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000438159 in std::swap<p2d::graphics::SpritePack*> (__a=@0x7ffffffe7430: 0xb16440, __b=@0x140: <error reading variable>) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/move.h:186
186       __a = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__b);
#0  0x0000000000438159 in std::swap<p2d::graphics::SpritePack*> (__a=@0x7ffffffe7430: 0xb16440, __b=@0x140: <error reading variable>) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/move.h:186
#1  0x00000000004380ef in std::__shared_ptr<p2d::graphics::SpritePack, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::swap (this=0x7ffffffe7430, __other=...) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1076
#2  0x00000000004380a6 in std::__shared_ptr<p2d::graphics::SpritePack, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::operator=(std::__shared_ptr<p2d::graphics::SpritePack, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>&&) (this=0x140, 
    __r=<unknown type in /path/to/project/build/src/p2d-run, CU 0x1072be, DIE 0x116f51>) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1000
#3  0x0000000000438042 in std::shared_ptr<p2d::graphics::SpritePack>::operator=(std::shared_ptr<p2d::graphics::SpritePack>&&) (this=0x140, 
    __r=<unknown type in /path/to/project/build/src/p2d-run, CU 0x1072be, DIE 0x116e9b>) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr.h:294
#4  0x0000000000438010 in p2d::graphics::Sprite::setSpritePack (this=0x0, spritePackArg=std::shared_ptr (empty) 0x0)
```

If there is information lacking here, I will add it as it is requested. For now, I don't see anything else to add further.

Comment: `this=0x0` and `this=0x140` look very, very bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the stacktrace you show there is this:

```
#4  0x0000000000438010 in p2d::graphics::Sprite::setSpritePack (this=0x0, spritePackArg
```

Which indicates that `setSpritePack` is being called on an object with a `nullptr` (this) `Sprite` object.

The problem you are having is *not* the assignment as such. It is that you are trying to assign to a member variable of a non-existing (`nullptr`) object.

You should investigate why the `Sprite` object is `nullptr` at the time you call `setSpritePack` on it - that's where your bug is.

Comment: This was indeed the problem. The called object in question was itself a shared pointer. As soon as I changed this, it works.